# run protractor plugins written in typescript

Tags: typescript, protractor

I want to make a protractor plugin using typescript. My project is alread running tests written in typescript.

in protractor.conf.js I added under plugins:

```
path: 'test-plugin.ts'
```

then I added the corresponding file in the e2e folder.
In tsconfig.json in the include part I added `"./e2e/test-plugin.ts"`

However I still get the following error when I try to run the tests:

> [12:19:49] E/launcher - Unexpected token export
>   [12:19:49] E/launcher - C:\develop\blabla\integrationTests\e2e\test-plugin.ts:1
>   (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { export function onPageLoad(): void {
>                                                                 ^^^^^^

I understand from that that the file is being read, but not interpreted as typescript.
What do I need to do to get it read as typescript file ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In protractor.conf.js you need to move typescript transpilation from `onPrepare` to `beforeLaunch` hook.

```
exports.config = {
  plugins: [{
    path: './path/to/my-plugin.ts',
  }],
  beforeLaunch: function() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: require('path').join(__dirname, './tsconfig.e2e.json')
    });
  }
  // ...
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, nice to see an answer when coming back from holidays. Now to be honest, I need to remember why I wanted to do this plugin. If my slow brain can get this information, I will give a try again.

Comment: @Olivvv Would you validate and accept the answer if it solves your problem?